# how to make a button on the top of other elements when the mouse move on the img?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

i made this button is dispaly :none and it will show up when the mouse move on the img-wrap, but there is a imge in this div, how to make a button on the top of other elements when the mouse move on the img or img-wrap? What is the appropriate way to solve this issue? I have tried using Z-index yet,but it did not work.

below is my js file.

```
import React from 'react';
import useFirestore from '../hooks/useFirestore';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import { projectFirestore } from '../firebase/config';
const ImageGrid = ({ setSelectedImg }) => {
  const { docs } = useFirestore('images');
  const db = projectFirestore.collection('images');
  return (
    <div className="img-grid">
      {docs &&
        docs.map(doc => (
          <motion.div
            className="img-wrap"
            key={doc.id}
            layout
            whileHover={{ opacity: 1 }}
            
          >
            <motion.img
              src={doc.url}
              alt="uploaded pic"
              initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
              animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
              transition={{ delay: 1 }}onClick={() => setSelectedImg(doc.url)}
            />
            <button className='showBt' onClick={() => db.doc(doc.id).delete()}>-</button>
          </motion.div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};
export default ImageGrid;
```

below is my css file.

```
/* image grid styles */
.img-grid {
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 40px;
}
.img-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
  padding: 50% 0;
  /* padding controls height, will always be perfectly square regardless of width */
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.img-wrap img {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-width: 150%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;

}
.img-wrap:hover .showBt {
  display: block;
}
.showBt {
  
  z-index: 6;
  margin: 60px auto;
  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `position: relative` to the button `.showBt`.